# Polite form of って in 「なになに」って何？

Tags: particles, spoken-language, keigo, politeness

How would you politely say that?
When you talk to a stranger, and you don't know the word he just said. Say f.e.:
落札
I understand that you could just say 「落札」の意味は何ですか？ but is there specifically a polite form of って ?

And to take it further, would there be even a Keigo version of って ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say

落札ってどういう意味？(casual)

落札ってどういう意味ですか？(polite)

落札とは、どういう意味でしょうか。(politer, formal)

Answer (score 1):

って in your example is an informal version of と言う (other usages are explained [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-572021))

と言う is a general set phrase (*something called something*) and does not identify the speaker, but you can ask specifically for a word someone said in a polite form replacing 言う with 仰る{おっしゃる}, for example 先ほどおっしゃった◯◯と言う言葉の意味は何ですか。

Comment: Is 仰る keigo or just teineigo? If Keigo, is it still ok to use です　in your example?

Comment: 仰る is a sonkeigo form of 言う, but I often hear it even in casual conversations to indicate who's words someone comments on (to differentiate between "as I said" vs "as you said"). Hmmm... ending with「何になりますか」 would be probably be ok in formal situations.